# "Failed connecting to the YubiKey. Make sure the application has the required permissions."

Tags: certificates, key, yubikey

I have a Yubikey version 5.2.7 and I can't generate any new certificates on yubikey manager app, which is weird since I have already generated two certs (on 9d slot) and they worked fine.

Now the following message pops up:

> "Failed connecting to the YubiKey. Make sure the application has the
> required permissions."

However, I ran the app as admin but the same error is showing up.

I read the [docs](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016648939-Troubleshooting-Failed-connecting-to-the-YubiKey-Make-sure-the-application-has-the-required-permissions-in-YubiKey-Manager) from yubico **but it doesn't provide any further help**.

I also tried to reset the key to factory settings, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: This looks more like a support call to the vendor. This is a specific issue with the app and not a security concern.